# Is it possible to get the source code of a Google Firebase (or Google Cloud Platform) project?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

I received access to a google firebase project and would like to get the source code of the functions. Is there a way to get to the source of the functions of that project?

**remark on the closing:**

I voted myself to close this question, because it is already answered *here* and there were needless comments still coming in. The other question mentioned here has nothing to do with this question except that the word "source" appears here and there.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because itis answered and there are still endless edits and comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can find your Cloud Functions code in the Google Cloud Platform console (not the Firebase console). As a matter of fact, your Firebase project is also a GCP project.

- Go to https://console.cloud.google.com/functions
- (If necessary, switch to the desired project)
- Open the "Function details" screen by clicking on the Function name
- Click on the "Source" tab

You can either copy/paste the code from the text area or use the "Download zip" button on the top-right corner of the screen.