# Source code is missing from google cloud functions list

Tags: google-cloud-functions

I am trying to retrieve the source code of a website/project which was made for me on fiverr. I've been made the owner of the project.
I followed the advice on previous links (below) to get the source code:

[Is it possible to get the source code of a Google Firebase (or Google Cloud Platform) project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69752244/is-it-possible-to-get-the-source-code-of-a-google-firebase-or-google-cloud-plat)

[Is it possible to retrieve Firebase Cloud Function source code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45298574/is-it-possible-to-retrieve-firebase-cloud-function-source-code)

[Get code from firebase console which I deployed earlier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43916490/get-code-from-firebase-console-which-i-deployed-earlier)

For some reason my google cloud functions list does not show “source” as stated in previous answers [picure with source missing in functions list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/txHFJ.png).
Is there another way to access the source code from google cloud?

Appreciated
J

Comment: Open Functions in Firebase interface. Click on Dashboard. Hover over one function, there should be 3 dots on the right side. Click on them --> click detail usage stats. It should take you to the page in GCP with the function. There you should see the "source" page. Where you should see the source code of your function. 

Btw if would be best if the guy who made you the site provided you with the source code ...

Comment: Thanks @pagep. When you say firebase interface which webpage are you referring to? The only one I am aware of is https://console.cloud.google.com/. When I click the 3 dots in this particular page for my project there is no "detail usage stats" link.             
p.s. I asked him already for the source code but he didnt respond, maybe he wants me to carry on paying him to do any website edits. So I've had to make him a "viewer only" of the project while i take control and make my own edits.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So its been over  a year and a bit more experience with Firebase. The correct answer is you cannot technically access the source code because the source code contains the html,css and javascript files which are deployed to the Firebase server and are back-end (server side). What you view on the website is only the front-end client side code and is not the full picture.

Whenever you get a website developed for you, you should always have the developer pass on all the html,css and javascript codes so that you can always deploy it when needed.